# Collection with automatic indexing in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Is there a collection in Java that its "put" method returns the automatic index it gave to the object, so in time you will be able to retrieve it/delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `HashMap` with your own extension. You can safely remove elements from it and the remaining elements will keep their indices.

```
class MyHashMap<T> {
    int index = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, T> internalMap = new HashMap<>();

    public int add(T t) {
        int temp = index++;
        internalMap.put(temp, t);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

If you need it to be thread-safe, then use an `AtomicInteger` for `index` and a `ConcurrentHashMap` for `internalMap`.

Answer (score 4):

All of the java.util.Map classes include a [`put(K key, V value)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) that allows you to provide a key via which you can later retrieve the object.

Comment: No, it's not like using a database with autoincrement primary key. As the name already says, Maps 'map'/'connect' one object to another

Comment: In the context of a put() method, what do you mean by automatic indexing?

Comment: The comment was not in the context of put() in all, it was based on the questions. I think the OP is aksing for a collection, which stores (comparable) elements in a map, where the key is just the hashCode or something like this and the put() will return this value. (which does not excist, indeed)

Answer (score 2):

You can always call `size()` of a `List` after adding (i.e. `add(element)`) an element to it. You'll still have to decrement the returned value by one to obtain the element's index.

Comment: if you delete one object, what happens to all the saved id's?

Comment: good point! if you are using the index right away before the list could have changed, then yes, sometimes I do it as well. But to make sure that you always get the correct index (no matter if the list changed or not) it's better to use `list.indexOf(element)`

Comment: @GameDroids, and to do that perfectly you need to implement the `equals()` method so if another instance of the same object is looked up, you can still find it in the list. Because 2 different object instances in java may still logically refer to the same object (i.e. same id, same username..etc)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the collection you are using. Most collections will give you a boolean in return to tell you if the element was added to the collection. But since there are many collections that are not in any particular order (and that order can change when working on the collection) the index wouldn't be correct anymore.

Some examples how you could retrieve the index:

```
// ArrayList, LinkedList (they put the new element at the end of the list)
list.add(myElement);
int index=list.size()-1;

// LinkedList , Stack... (with "push" the new element will be put at the beginning of the list)
list.push(myElement);
int index = 0;
```

If the collection has an Index (not maps) then you can retrieve that index by calling

```
 int index = myCollection.indexOf(myElement);
```

**edit** I forgot to add, that this necessitates to implement an equality test by overriding `equals(Object o)`. (Thank you Muhammad Gelbana) **/edit**

This is actually the safest method to make sure that the index is the correct one even when the collection changed .

But of course there are way too many different collections with different goals, to be sure of how to retrieve the index. E.g. Maps usually don't have an index but a "key" which you have to provide yourself.

You can of course create your own collection and make sure you always have the correct index. Either you implement a `map` as it was already suggested, or you use an array:

```
public class MyCollection{
    private E[] array;

   public MyCollection<E>(){
       array = new E[0];
   }

   public int put(E element){
      // create a new array that can hold one more element
      E[] copy = new E[array.length+1];
      // copy the old array into a new array
      int i=0;
      for(;i<array.length;i++){
         copy[i] = array[i];
      }
      copy[i]=element;
      return i;
   }
}
```